# Validating 0-0 people on step by step jquery form

Tags: jquery

On step 2 of my step by step jquery form I'm trying to get the form to output an inline error when the user makes a selection in the range 0-0 because it's not a valid input. How do I go about doing this?

http://jsfiddle.net/xSkgH/39/

Comment: Why not just change the configuration on the slider so the minimum value is not zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not difficult. You just need to check both values of the slider before you allow them to continue. Your error message behaves a little funky (outside the scope of your question), but this should answer your question.

```
// validate second-step
var lower = $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0);
var upper = $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1);

if(lower == 0 && upper == 0) {
    $("#errorMessage").html('Please select two values other than 0 and 0!');
    return false;
}
```